# Why is garbage value stored at an address equal to its address in a C code

Tags: c, pointers

I came across this weird code, I understand that incrementing the pointer and printing that value is unsafe in this case but what's interesting here is the value which is supposed to be garbage is instead equal to its address. Can someone explain me why is it so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int x = 10;
    int *p = &x;

    printf("Address before: %d, Value before: %d\n", p, *p);
    p++;
    printf("Address after:  %d, Value after:  %d\n", p, *p);
}
```

Output:

```
Address before: 6422036, Value before: 10
Address after:  6422040, Value after:  6422040
```

Why is the value stored at address 6422040 equal to 6422040 and not some random garbage value.
I ran the code multiple times to make sure it wasn't just a coincidence but it still gives the same result.

Comment: `x` and `p` are probably adjacent to each other in the memory. So once you increment the address of `x` you hit the address of `p`. Not much of a mystery

Comment: `p` just happens to be after `x` in memory. So `p++` changes `p` to point to itself. You can't rely on that behavior. The compiler is free to put `p` and `x` at any location.

Comment: Actually that makes total sense. Why didn't I think of that... Thanks :)

Comment: Note that reading outside the bounds of an object has undefined results. You're getting a very logical visible behaviour here, but theoretically that code could have launched a nuclear strike on Antarctica.

Comment: `6422040` *is* some random garbage value. It's "randomly" the pointer's own value, it could have been "randomly" something else's representation. The result could be anything. It might also not print anything, it might crash, or might print `10` again.

Comment: Yes, but it's a legitimate question that's seen, in one variant or another, several times a day. Its long-term usefulness is low.

Comment: I understand that, and i know actual answer is always going to be a garbage value. It so happens in this case that `x` and `p` got adjacent memory hence incrementing `p` gave same value as its address. My sole question was to understand this behavior that what was the reason for same values being displayed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer:
`x` and `p` happen to be adjacent in memory(for this case, there is no guarantee that they will always get adjacent memory). So after incrementing p, p starts to point to itself. Hence the same values.

Comment: You got one answer from an infinite pool of possible answers. The behaviour of undefined behaviour is, unsurprisingly, undefined. Don't count on this result in all cases.

Comment: I understand that, and i know actual answer is always going to be a garbage value. It so happens in this case that `x` and `p` got adjacent memory hence incrementing `p` gave same value as its address. My sole question was to understand this behavior that what was the reason for same values being displayed :)

Comment: @user4581301 : You are confusing undefined behaviour with actual behaviour.  The question is about the actual behaviour and this is a plausible and most likely explanation for the observed behaviour.  If it exhibited different behaviour the question would not arise.  He is not _relying_ in this behaviour; he is simply observing it and asking how this has occurred.  There are not an _infinite pool of possible answers_ to this _finite_ behaviour.  Any behaviour; whatever it is will have a finite explanation.

Comment: I'll take that. Pretty much any other behaviour would mean the implementation was up to something particularly interesting.